# PHP Create an encode algorithm?

Tags: php, algorithm, decode, encode

```
function deCode_Me($strContent, $cKey){
    $hRet = 0;
    $sRet = "";
    foreach( str_split($strContent) as $nKey ){
        $sRet .= chr(ord($nKey) ^ ord($cKey[$hRet++ % strlen($cKey)]));
    }
    return $sRet;
```

}

How can I make the encoder for the above resolver.
the exact opposite?

Comment: Do the same steps, but in reverse. Hint: `^` is XOR, `A ^ B = C`, and `C ^ B = A`

Comment: I'm very nervous. would you do it for me. (very important to me)
I can not write the encryptor

Comment: No. This is *not* a code writing service.

Comment: [so] is *not* a free code writing service. You are expected to try to **write the code yourself**. After [doing more research](//meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592) if you have a problem you can **post what you've tried** with a **clear explanation of what isn't working** and providing a [**Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](//stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). I suggest reading [ask] a good question and [the perfect question](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/). Also, be sure to take the [tour] read [this](//meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/347937/)

Answer (score 0):

```
function encode_Me($strContent, $cKey)
{
$key = $cKey;
$text = $strContent;
$outText = '';
for ($i = 0; $i < strlen($text); $i++)
    {
    for ($j = 0; $j < strlen($key); $j++, $i++)
        {
        $outText.= $text
            {
            $i} ^ $key
                {
                $j};
                }
            }

        return $outText;
        }
```

worked ! :)